\ifstrequal argument expansion
when using \ifstrequal in \ifstrequal{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!} , the result is False! Anyone knows what happened here ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\ifstrequal{5}{5}{True!}{False!} % print True!

\edef\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\myvar}{5}{True!}{False!} % print True!

\ifstrequal{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!} % print False! 

\end{document}


why is this unexpected? (this is a genuine question - I'm not sure what needs explaining beyond 'they're different, so the test fails', which is technically the answer.)

Unlike with other programming languages/programming paradigms, TeX does not really come along with a concept of a data type "string". Instead, everything in TeX is "token". If the term "string" is encountered while referring to matters of TeX, then clarification is needed about what is meant/denoted by this term. ...

... Afaik with \ifstrequal a "string" is the result of in the stage of expansion applying the primitive operation \detokenize on the tokens that form the argument in question (without the tokens forming the argument being expanded beforehand!). This in turn implies that here the term "string" denotes a sequence of explicit character tokens of category 12(other); exception: space character tokens produced by the primitive operation \detokenize are of category 10(space).

Why do you want to use a string comparison on something returned by \fpeval? That sounds rather counterproductive. Better use \fp_compare:nTF or \fp_compare:nNnTF for this (as in your newer question).

thanks for your tip. I'll use \fp_compare .

If you are considering using \expandafer to \fpeval{2+3} then you can try
{\tracingmacros=2 \tracingcommands=2 \fpeval{2+3}}

and look into the log file. You can count that TeX must expand 343 expandable primitives and 135 macros in order to calculate 2+3. If you want to expand this before starting another macro than each elementary expansion step doubles the number of \expandafter needed. It means that you have to prefix 2^{479}-1 expadafters. This is practically impossible. Moreover, the umber of expansion activities depends on the formula you want to evaluate. But we have \expanded primitive which does fully expansion, i.e. it does all 479 expansion steps in a "single run". You can do:
 \expandafter\ifstrequal\expanded{{\fpeval{2+3}}}{5}{True!}{False!}

Just for comparison, try this in OpTeX:
{\tracingmacros=2 \tracingcommands=2 \expr[0]{2+3}}

and look to the log.file. You can count that LauTeX needs to exapnd 7 expandable primitives and 6 macros in order to evaluate 2+3. This is a lot of smaller quantities that LaTeX's \fpeval.

thanks.  is \expanded{{\fpeval{  }}} identical to \expanded{\fpeval{  }} ? The former has additional {} .

@xcn no, it is not identical. If you suppose the 2+3 example mentioned here, then the first one expands to \ifstrequal{5}{5} but the second bad one expands to \ifstrequal5{5}. Both returns true because there is only one digit. But 7+5 will not work, because it expands (in the second bad case) to \ifstrequal12{5} and 1 will be compared with 2 and 5 will be printed.

Thanks for your excellent answer.

The strings are different, so they aren't equal, so the false branch is executed:

The first consists of \, f, p, e , v, a, l, {, 2, +, 3 and }.
The second consists simply of 5.

\ifstrequal{5}{5}{True!}{False!} % print True!

Here the strings are the same. 5 and 5.
\edef\myvar{\fpeval{2+3}}
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\myvar}{5}{True!}{False!} % print True!

Here \myvar is 5 and this is expanded before the test is applied, so this is like the first case: 5 and 5.
\ifstrequal{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!} % print False! 

Here no expansion is done, so the arguments are turned into strings as is. Here is what the manual says about the test:

Compares two strings and executes  if they are equal, and  otherwise. The strings are not expanded in the test and the comparison is category code agnostic. Control sequence tokens in any of the  arguments will be detokenized and treated as strings. This command is robust.

If you must use this because you object to expl3 and prefer to make things difficult for yourself, the easiest way is to just cheat and stick \ExpandArgs{e} in front. For example
\ExpandArgs{e}\ifstrequal{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!}

Since you are using etoolbox and \fpeval, I assume you don't require an answer in terms of \expandafters etc.
To expand things with \expandafter etc., you need to know how many expansions things require to fully expand. Try this:
\def\tempa{\fpeval{2+3}}
\meaning\tempa

No expansion - baseline. Then compare, say,
\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa{\fpeval{2+3}}
\meaning\tempa

Notice this gives exactly the same result. We expanded the second \expandafter before \def and expanded the { before \tempa. So not much progress.
expl3
Rather than using etoolbox, which is only really needed for patching existing commands these days, you could just use expl3. The most obvious test is, of course, to just compare the floating points.
\fp_compare:nNnTF { 2+3 } = { 5 } { Equal } { Unequal }

produces Equal.
If for some reason you really do need a string test here,
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { enTF }
\str_if_eq:enTF { \fp_eval:n { 2 + 3 } } { 5 } { Same } { Different }

produces Same.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_compare:nNnTF { 2+3 } = { 5 } { Equal } { Unequal }
\par
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { enTF }
\str_if_eq:enTF { \fp_eval:n { 2 + 3 } } { 5 } { Same } { Different }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


well , even if I try to use \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!} instead , it still prints False! .  how to expand it correctly ?

I have the same question. why two \expandafter not working? I thought \fpeval is expandable.

@xcn well, how difficult do you want to make it? is 'stick \ExpandArgs{e} in front' an acceptable answer?

@Tom  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expanded{\fpeval{2+3}}{5}{True!}{False!}  this works.

@Tom see edit ..

@xcn well, if you are allowed to use \expanded. why \expanded and \fpeval but not \ExpandArgs?

@cfr  \ExpandArgs is a more concise answer.  I just curious about \expandafter method.

@xcn well, there's a reason you so often see \edef\tempa{} etc. in code :-).

@xcn see expl3 version. I don't know why you are using string tests, so I gave both. for the example, counts would make more sense than fps, but that may not work in your real case.

@cfr much appreciated for your assistance . I don't use string tests at present , \fpeval expansion in the case is what I cared about.

@xcn @Tom \expandafter triggers only a single(!) step of expansion on the next but one token if that is expandable while with \fpeval several(!) steps of expansion are needed for obtaining the result. Afaik with \fpeval the amount of expansion steps needed to get the result is not predictable as that depends on what tokens are given as \fpeval's argument. ...

@xcn @Tom ...In order to get the result of \fpeval you need to use s.th., which, unlike \expandafter, does not trigger just one single expansion step on the next but one token, but where expansion steps are triggered on expandable tokens repetitively and automatically with all tokens of the argument until a constellation of tokens is obtained whereof all are unexpandable. Something like \edef or \xdef or \expanded or \ExpandArgs{e}....

@xcn You might be interested in the answers to the question How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?, especially the \def\top{\first 0 } \def\first{\second 1 }...-thingie.

@UlrichDiez thanks for your elaboration. I'll try to understand them.
